# Completion Suggester Not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

```
{
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "filter": {
            "autocomplete_filter": {
                "type": "edgeNGram",
                "min_gram": 1,
                "max_gram": 20
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {
            "autocomplete": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "autocomplete_filter"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
"mappings": {
    "test": {
        "properties": {
            "suggest": {
                "type": "completion",
                "analyzer": "autocomplete"
            },
            "hostname": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
`

Above mapping is stored in Elastic search.

`POST index/test
    {
      "hostname": "testing-01",
      "suggest": [{"input": "testing-01"}]
    }`


    `POST index/test
    {
      "hostname": "testing-02",
      "suggest": [{"input":"testing-02"}]
    }`


    `POST index/test
    {
      "hostname": "w1-testing-01",
      "suggest": [{"input": "w1-testing-01"}]
    }`

    POST index/test
    {
      "hostname": "w3-testing-01",
      "suggest": [{"input": "w3-testing-01"}]
    }
`
When there are 30 documents with hostname starting w1 and hostnames w3, when term "w3" is searched, I get suggestions of all w1 first and then w3.
Suggestion Query

```
{
"query": {
    "_source": {
        "include": [
            "text"
        ]
    },
    "suggest": {
        "server-suggest": {
            "text": "w1",
            "completion": {
                "field": "suggest",
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Tried different analyzers, same issue. 
can some body guide ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common trap. It is because the `min_ngram` is 1, and hence, both `w1-testing-01` and `w3-testing-01` will produce the token `w`. Since you only specified  `analyzer`, the `autocomplete` analyzer will also kick in at search time and hence searching suggestions for `w3` will also produce the token `w`, hence why both `w1-testing-01` and `w3-testing-01` match.

The solution is to add a `search_analyzer` to your `suggest` field so that the `autocomplete` analyzer is not used at search time (you can use the `standard`, `keyword` or whatever analyzer makes sense for your use case), but only at indexing time.

```
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "suggest": {
          "type": "completion",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"        <-- add this
        },
        "hostname": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: If there are 30 documents starting with both w1 and w3, still the results starts with w1. We need suggestions including hiphens. Standard analyzer will not include hiphens. What do you suggest ?

Comment: Fair enough, the `standard` analyzer discards hyphens, use the `keyword`analyzer then.

Comment: Thank you Val. I will update the mapping and re-index the data.

Comment: Its working as expected now. Tokenizer for autocomplete analyzer is changed to whitespace. Thank yoou Val